# Meaning of “parler par figure”

Tags: sens, expressions

> « Que fais-tu Patachou? »
>
> Il est au fond du jardin. Il est tourné vers la maison et, de temps en
>   temps, il pousse un petit cri. Il écoute ; puis il rit.
>
> « Je fais le poète ! me repond-il. Cela n'est pas bien difficile. Dès
>   que j'ai dit un mot, on me donne la rime. Mais il faut crier assez
>   fort.
>   C'est l'écho, c'est la poésie... »
>
> « **Tu ne crois pas si bien
>   dire**, Patachou ; et, sans le savoir dire, **tu parles par figure**.

This is from "Patachou" by Tristan Dreme.
I do not understand the meaning of the sentences below.

1. Tu ne crois pas si bien dire,
2. tu parles par figure.

I am so glad if somebody kindly teach me.

Answer (score 4):

*Tu ne crois pas si bien dire* is a common phrase that means "You are definitely right, even more than you could imagine". You have to understand this phrase as "you don't believe that you are so right when you are saying this".

As for *figure*, I understand it here as as *figure de style*, which has the same meaning as *figure of speech* in English. As Patachou tries to speak like a poet, he uses figures of speech (eg metaphors) without even knowing it.

Comment: Thank yo so much,Greg. for your  kind and detailed  answer!!

Comment: I think you are being too technical with "figure de style". 
"Parler" is probably used as a synonym for "image": "parler par image".
But anyway it does not change the meaning of the sentence.